# Table of contents ignores bottom margin

Tags: table-of-contents, margins

When my TOC spans across multiple pages, the bottom margin is ignored.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

%Packages
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos,prependcaption,textsize=tiny]{todonotes}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{listings} % used for code-snippets
\usepackage[english]{babel} % the main document language is the last one
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{xargs}                
\usepackage{tabularx}      
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{siunitx}

%Bibliography
\usepackage[style=iso-authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{./bibliography/bibliography.bib}

%Glossary
\usepackage[acronym,shortcuts,automake]{glossaries}
\glspatchtabularx
\makeglossaries

%Formatting
    %Margins
    \usepackage[a4paper,
    left=4cm,right=2cm,top=4cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}

    %Line-spacing
    \usepackage{setspace}
    \onehalfspacing
    
    %Linenumbers
    \usepackage{lineno}
    %\linenumbers
    
    %Margins
    \usepackage{showframe}
    
    %Header
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    
%Abbreviations
[...]

\begin{document}
    \pagenumbering{Roman}   
    
    \todo{Remove list of todos}
    \listoftodos
    \newpage
    
    %Titlepage
    \input{content/titlepage}
    
    %Table of contents
    \todo{Bottom-margin does not apply to toc}
    \setcounter{page}{2}
    \tableofcontents
    
    [...]

\end{document}
```

This is how my TOC looks like:
[image: TOC with margin error].

Am I missing something? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Needless to say, this is not normal behavior, but there are ways to cause it to happen.  So somewhere in your preamble you are doing something naughty.  More that than I cannot say without seeing a Mnimal Working Example which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @JohnKormylo I added the preamble... Maybe you could have a look at it now.

Comment: The problem comes from the combination of setspace and lineno, both of which modify \output for nefarious purposes.

Comment: @JohnKormylo sadly this didn't solve my problem. The overflow still occurs, even when I deactivate both setspace and lineno.

Comment: Works on my version (used a loop to generate 30 sections).  All I have to do is remove either one.